# UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor field value cannot be retrieved at server end in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel-5, ckeditor

I am setting up unisharp/ckeditor in laravel form using https://artisansweb.net/install-use-ckeditor-laravel/ installation guide.
I followed all the steps mentioned in here, but I am not able to get value of ckeditor in my php-laravel code.

Here is my code,

Entry in provider array in config/app/js,

```
 Unisharp\Ckeditor\ServiceProvider::class,
```

Entry in html file,

```
<body>
        @include('inc.navbar')
        <div class="container starter-template">
            @include('inc.message')
            @yield('content')
        </div>
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
<script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'summary-ckeditor' );
</script>
</body>
```

Entry in html file to add ckeditor in form,

```
<div class='form-group'>
        {{Form::label('body', 'Body')}}
        {{Form::text('body', '', ['id' => 'summary-ckeditor', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Body'])}}
    </div>
```

My composer entries,

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.7.*",
        "unisharp/laravel-ckeditor": "^4.7"
    },
```

Let me know what am I missing on.

Comment: Why you want use a library to do that? Use original CKEditor instead

Comment: @ArashHatami How do I achieve that? I am sorry to ask if it is silly but I am new in this field. please bare with me. Can give me some reference links?

Comment: Check official documentation https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_installation.html

Comment: This is a great solution but it doesn't go with my coding pattern. I am using laravel, so I am not convinced to add this in my root directory instead of node_modules directory.